# ORA-29024: Certificate validation failure

Tags: sql, oracle, ssl, https, oracle11g

I've followed the following tutorials :
[Create wallet](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/utl_http-and-ssl.php),[Create ACL](http://www.oracleflash.com/36/Oracle-11g-Access-Control-List-for-External-Network-Services.html)

And I am still getting `ORA-29024: Certificate validation failure` error.

I'm trying this query :

```
    UTL_HTTP.set_wallet('file:/home/oracle/wallet', 'password');
  l_http_request  := UTL_HTTP.begin_request('https://somedomain.co.il');
  l_http_response := UTL_HTTP.get_response(l_http_request);
```

Now i've added to the ACL : *.somedomain.co.il,somedomain.co.il

And I've downloaded the certificate as DER encoded, as I've read somewhere that this is the one needed and didn't get any errors in the proccess of generating the wallet.

Any thoughts?

I'm using Oracle 11g

Comment: http://eternal-donut.blogspot.com/2008/07/tip-5-using-utlhttp-and-ssl.html Try this..

Comment: @Senthil Prabhu You happen to know how i can remove a cert because i can't seem to follow that tutorial because it already exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end my problem was when I exported the certificate i choose DER, in my case i should have used PCKS # 7, but this won't most likley work in all cases i guess it depends on the key.

So i guess if you landed here try and play with your certificate files (be sure to remove and re-add)
And very important, change sessions between tries to know if it worked or not because otherwise it'll keep giving you the error all though it should work.

Comment: "change sessions between tries to know if it worked or not" saved my day.

Comment: Maybe this procedure on using the GUI tools to register certificates also helps others interested: http://www.invantive.com/about-invantive/news/entryid/1027/import-a-pfx-file-in-oracle-wallet